# best way to run python generator cleanup code

Tags: python, generator, mysql-python

I'm trying to write a generator function that gets rows out of a database and returns them one at a time. However, I'm not sure if the cleanup code marked ** below executes as I think it does. If it does not, what is the best way to put cleanup code inside a generator itself that executes after the last yield statement? I looked at catching StopIteration but that seems to be done from the caller, not within the generator.

```
def MYSQLSelectGenerator(stmt):
...
try:   
    myDB = MySQLdb.connect(host=..., port=..., user=..., passwd=..., db=...)   
    dbc=myDB.cursor()
    dbc.execute(stmt)
    d = "asdf"
    while d is not None:
        d = dbc.fetchone() #can also use fetchmany() to be more efficient
        yield d
    dbc.close() #** DOES THIS WORK AS I INTEND, MEANING AS SOON AS d = "None"
except MySQLdb.Error, msg:
    print("MYSQL ERROR!")
    print msg
```

Comment: Don't have any experiance but you might want to add a ```finally``` clause and put the cleanup in there - looks like that is what it was intended for.  [The **try** statement](http://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a context manager and the `with` statement. [**`contextlib`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html) provides [**`closing`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.closing):

```
from contextlib import closing

myDB = MySQLdb.connect(host=..., port=..., user=..., passwd=..., db=...)   
with closing(myDB.cursor()) as dbc:
    dbc.execute(stmt)
    d = "asdf"
    while d is not None:
        d = dbc.fetchone() #can also use fetchmany() to be more efficient
        yield d
```

This will automatically call `close()` on `dbc` at the end of the `with` block, even if an exception has been raised.

Comment: I had formally accepted Ben's answer but this answer is more correct because context managers already handle this complexity.

Answer (score 5):

Your version will run `dbc.close()` as soon as `d is None`, but *not if an exception gets raised*. You need a [`finally` clause](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#defining-clean-up-actions). This version is *guaranteed* to run `dbc.close()` even if an exception gets raised:

```
try:   
    myDB = MySQLdb.connect(host=..., port=..., user=..., passwd=..., db=...)   
    dbc = myDB.cursor()
    dbc.execute(stmt)
    d = "asdf"
    while d is not None:
        d = dbc.fetchone() #can also use fetchmany() to be more efficient
        yield d
except MySQLdb.Error, msg:
    print("MYSQL ERROR!")
    print msg
finally:
    dbc.close()
```

Comment: is there any way to combine the two? The problem with this approach is that  dbc.close() is no longer in a try block that catches mysql errors as it was in my version. Is the answer to put another try block in the finally clause? thats ugly but..

Comment: Good API design dictates that methods like `close` shouldn't throw exceptions (other than in cases like the connection already being closed), because clients will be left in a state where you're not sure whether the connection got cleaned up or not. You should confirm this with the authors of the library in question, but I suspect it'd be safe to assume that there won't be any exceptions from that line.

Comment: The code in `finally` gets run both is there is an error and if there is no error

Answer (score 5):

One thing you could do is use a `finally` clause. Another option (that may be overkill here but is a useful thing to know about) is to make a class that works with the `with` statement:

```
class DatabaseConnection:
    def __init__(self, statement):
        self.statemet = statement
    def __enter__(self): 
        self.myDB = MySQLdb.connect(host=..., port=...,user=...,passwd=...,db=...)
        self.dbc = myDB.cursor()
        self.dbc.execute(self.statement)
        self.d = "asdf"
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        self.dbc.close()

    def __iter__(self):
        while self.d is not None:
            self.d = self.dbc.fetchone()
            yield self.d


with DatabaseConnection(stmnt) as dbconnection:
    for i in dbconnection:
        print(i)
```