# How to clean up in a generator if not finished

Tags: python, generator, resource-cleanup

If I have a generator like the following, which requires setup and cleaning up, and is able to produce as many records as needed. However my user may stop asking for records at any point. In that case my `res.Cleanup()` will not be ran. What is the right way of carrying out such cleaning up work?

```
def MyGenerator():
  res = SetupResource()
  while True:
    yield res.ProduceOne()
  res.Cleanup()

def UserCode():
  for x in MyGenerator():
    print x
    if Tired():
      return
```

UPDATE:

Here is a runnable example:

```
def MyGenerator():
  print 'Setup Resource'
  while True:
    yield 'This is a record.'
  print 'Clean up'

def UserCode():
  i = 0
  for x in MyGenerator():
    print x
    i += 1
    if i > 5:
      return
```

Comment: it does sound like a job for a context manager

Comment: Thank you! I tried putting `SetupResource` and `Cleanup` in a context manager and use it from inside the `MyGenerator`. The `Cleanup` is not called either. What is the way you are thinking of?

Comment: @shaoyl85 please provide a [mcve], not just a description

Comment: well, I was thinking of using the context manager outside the generator i.e.  `with MyGenerator() as mg: for x in mg...`

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Done. Thank you!

Comment: have you seen [this SO Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19411446/best-way-to-run-python-generator-cleanup-code)?

Comment: @Pynchia: You mean `MyGenerator` is a context manager which yields a generator and then performs a cleanup after it's yield? That should work!

Comment: yes, as it is described in the link I have provided above (2nd answer), you put the setup code in the `__enter__` and the cleanup code in the `__exit__` methods, as you normally would with a context manager.

Comment: @Pynchia: I see. Thank you very much!